# RecyclerView Item Getting Clicked When Click on FloatingActionButton in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, floating-action-button

I have a `FloatingActionButton` over a `RecyclerView` in my app. The `Button` is showing ok, but when I click on it, the `RecyclerView` item below it is getting the click event, instead of the button. If I set the `RecyclerView` to show over the `FloatingActionButton`, the `Button` works as intended.

How to solve this, and make the `Button` to get the click event?

Thank you.

Comment: Put the FAB inside Relative layout or LinearLayout and set that layout property to android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" and its done.

Comment: Fab.bringToFront() and add clickable:true in xml

Comment: If you use android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" for the button not matter it will take click if you set OnClick Listener on the button.

Answer (score 6):

It can only happen if you don't set  onClick Listener on `FloatingActionButton`. So just set onClick Listener on `FloatingActionButton` Your problem will be solved....

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Your code to do something if you have
        }
});
```

If have on action to do just implement a empty listener like above ..

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use FrameLayout for screen. you can get all click event,item or floating button.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</FrameLayout>
```